# .Net Core Dependency Injection Get different instance generated by Two Factory Methods

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have two static classes with single static factory method for each.

```
public static class First
{
 public IMyService Factory()
 {
   return IMyService()
   {
    //configure with Configs
   };
 }
}

public static class Second
{
 public IMyService Factory()
 {
  return IMyService()
  {
   // configure with different Configs
  };
 }
}
```

The following would make provider return an instance when asked for:

```
   services.AddSingleton(mb =>
            {
                var myService= First.Factory();
                return myService;
            });
```

How do I call different factories when need to get an instance with different configs?

Comment: is it a one-time decision (e.g. on app startup) or you will need both during one app lifecycle?

Comment: I think you need a factory for your factories.

Comment: @MaximZabolotskikh an instance will be used by the same class always

Comment: @YahyaHussein if you create the *same* service with different configuration you don't need a factory at all, much less two. You need to inject the *configuration* into the service class's constructor

Answer (score 1):

**If it's a one-time decision (app startup)** than you should extract your config as a dependency:

in appsettings.json:

```
"mysettings":{"bla":"val1"}
```

somewhere in project:

```
public class mysettings { public string bla {get;set; }
```

in myservice constructor:

```
public myservice(IOptions<mysettings> settings) { ... }
```

in startup.cs:

```
services.Configure<mysettings>(this.Configuration.GetSection("mysettings"));
services.AddSingleton<Imyservice, myservice>();
```

Like this you inject the settings and your service will be instantiated with those that are specified in the appsettings.json

**If you need to deside "live" which settings to use:**

```
public interface IMyServiceFactory{
  IMyService Create(MySettings settings);
}
```

Than you inject IMyServiceFactory to the class where you want to use IMyService and instantate it there with the right settings. Or even:

```
public interface IMyServiceFactory{
  IMyService Create1();
  IMyService Create2();
}
```

In any case you just register the factory in startup:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyServiceFactory, MyServiceFactory>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your client code or the bootstrapping code needs to express what kind of implementation is needed. You could implement it the following way:

```
public Interface IReqeust
{
    // Some code
}

public class HttpRequest : IRequest
{
    // Implementation
}

public class TcpRequest : IRequest
{
    // Implementation
}
```

One way could be to offer multiple methods. You can still hide the configuration but some implementation details leak into your client code.

```
public Interface IRequestFactory
{
    IRequest CreateHttpRequest();

    IRequest CreateTcpRequest();
}

public class RequestFactory : IRequestFactory
{
    // Implementation
}
```

Another solution would be to determine whats needed while constructing your factory.

```
public Interface IRequestFactory
{
    IRequest CreateRequest();
}

public class RequestFactory : IRequestFactory
{
    private IConfigReader configReader;

    public RequestFactory(IConfigReader configReader)
    {
        this.configReader = configReader;
    }

    public IRequest CreateRequest()
    {
        var currentProtocoll = configReader.GetCurrentProtocoll();
        if(currentProtocoll is HTTP)
            return new HttpRequest();
        else
            return new TcpRequest();
    }
}
```

I would not recommend your solution with more factories. At least not with what you wrote so far.